# ')' and ;' expected error in Spark Framework

Tags: java, maven, java-8

I am trying to run this example:

```
package com.mycompany.app;

import static spark.Spark.*;

/**
 * Hello world!
 *
 */
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        get("/hello", (req, res) -> "Hello World");
    }
}
```

`mvn package` but I get this error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile
>   (default-compile) on project my-app: Compilation failure: Compilation
>   failure: [ERROR]
>   /Users/riccardo.tacconi/riccardo/java/spark/my-app/src/main/java/com/mycompany/app/App.java:[11,27]
>   ')' expected [ERROR]
>   /Users/riccardo.tacconi/riccardo/java/spark/my-app/src/main/java/com/mycompany/app/App.java:[11,35]
>   illegal start of expression [ERROR]
>   /Users/riccardo.tacconi/riccardo/java/spark/my-app/src/main/java/com/mycompany/app/App.java:[11,50]
>   ';' expected [ERROR] -> [Help 1]

The error:

```
App.java:[11,27] ')' expected
```

refers to (req, res) between req and ,.

The error:

```
App.java:[11,35]
```

refers to -> operator. It seems to me that this line:

```
get("/hello", (req, res) -> "Hello World");
```

it is not valid Java syntax. I wonder if Maven is compiling using another Java version (an older one?). This is the version I have installed:

```
» java -version                                                                                                                                                                                   riccardo.tacconi@RTACCONI-01
java version "1.8.0_11"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_11-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.11-b03, mixed mode)
```

That's the pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>my-app</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sparkjava</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Provide the relevant lines of code in `App.java` file to help you fix them, but notice that the compiler error is very descriptive.

Comment: Are your Maven settings for Java 8?

Comment: I added the pom. I do not have the Java version in the pom. I guess Maven should pickup the default Java version. I am using 1.8.0_11. Spark does not support 1.7

Comment: Yes, your 1.8 JDK is used. But Maven uses 1.5 for source and target format by default: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/

Answer (score 4):

The line

```
get("/hello", (req, res) -> "Hello World");
```

is valid Java 8 syntax using a Lambda.

You should make sure that your Maven `pom.xml` is configured to compile for Java 8, not for Java 7 or earlier. Use this setting for the [Maven Compiler Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html).

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    [...]
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    [...]
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```

The site of this plugin [describes your problem](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/):

> Also note that at present the default source setting is 1.5 and the default target setting is 1.5, independently of the JDK you run Maven with